# Linq - reuse expression on child property

Tags: linq, lambda

Not sure if what I am trying is possible or not, but I'd like to reuse a linq expression on an objects parent property.

With the given classes:

```
class Parent {
 int Id { get; set; }
 IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
 string Name { get; set; }
}
class Child{
 int Id { get; set; }
 Parent Dad { get; set; }
 string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If i then have a helper

```
Expression<Func<Parent,bool> ParentQuery() { 
  Expression<Func<Parent,bool> q = p => p.Name=="foo";
}
```

I then want to use this when querying data out for a child, along the lines of:

```
using(var context=new Entities.Context) {
 var data=context.Child.Where(c => c.Name=="bar" 
 && c.Dad.Where(ParentQuery));
}
```

I know I can do that on child collections:

```
using(var context=new Entities.Context) {
 var data=context.Parent.Where(p => p.Name=="foo" 
 && p.Childen.Where(childQuery));
}
```

but cant see any way to do this on a property that isnt a collection.
This is just a simplified example, actually the ParentQuery will be more complex and I want to avoid having this repeated in multiple places as rather than just having 2 layers I'll have closer to 5 or 6, but all of them will need to reference the parent query to ensure security.

If this isnt possible, my other thought was to somehow translate the ParentQuery expression to be of the given type so effectively:
    p => p.Name=="foo";
turns into:
    c => c.Dad.Name=="foo";
but using generics / some other form of query builder that allows this to retain the parent query and then just have to build a translator per child object that substitutes in the property route to the parent.

> EDIT:
>   Following on from comments by  @David morton

Initially that looks like I can just change from Expression to a delegate function and then call
    .Where(ParentQuery()(c.Dad));

However I am using this in a wider repository pattern and cant see how I can use this with generics and predicate builders - I dont want to retrieve rows from the store and filter on the client (web server in this case).  I have a generic get data method that takes in a base expression query.  I then want to test to see if the supplied type implements ISecuredEntity and if it does append the securityQuery for the entity we are dealing with.

```
public static IList<T> GetData<T >(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) {
 IList<T> data=null;
 var secQuery=RepositoryHelperers.GetScurityQuery<T>();
 if(secQuery!=null) {
  query.And(secQuery);
 }
 using(var context=new Entities.Context()) {
  var d=context.GetGenericEntitySet<T>();
  data=d.ToList();
 }
 return data;
}
```

ISecuredEntity:

```
public interface ISecuredEntity : IEntityBase {
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> SecurityQuery<T>();
}
```

Example Entity:

```
public partial class ExampleEntity:  ISecuredEntity {
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> SecurityQuery<T>() {
        //get specific type expression and make generic
        Type genType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(ExampleEntity), typeof(bool));
       var q = this.SecurityQuery(user);
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(genType, q.Body, q.Parameters);         
    }

     public Expression<Func<ExampleEntity, bool>> SecurityQuery() {
        return e => e.OwnerId==currentUser.Id;

    }
}
```

and repositoryHelpers:

```
internal  static partial class RepositoryHelpers {
    internal static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SecureQuery<T>() where T : new() {
        var instanceOfT = new T();
        if (typeof(Entities.ISecuredEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
            return ((Entities.ISecuredEntity)instanceOfT).SecurityQuery<T>();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> EDIT Here is the (eventual) solution

I ended up going back to using expressions, and using LinqKit Invoke.  Note: for EF I also had to call .AsExpandable() on the entitySet

The key part is being able to call:

```
 Product.SecureFunction(user).Invoke(pd.ParentProduct);
```

so that I can pass in the context into my parent query

My end classes look like:

```
public interface ISecureEntity {
 Func<T,bool> SecureFunction<T>(UserAccount user);
}


public class Product : ISecureEntity {
 public Expression<Func<T,bool>> SecureFunction<T>(UserAccount user) {
  return SecureFunction(user) as Expression<Func<T,bool>>; 
 }
 public static Expression<Func<Product,bool>> SecureFunction(UserAccount user) {
  return f => f.OwnerId==user.AccountId;
 }
 public string Name { get;set; }
 public string OwnerId { get;set; }
}


public class ProductDetail : ISecureEntity {
 public Expression<Func<T,bool>> SecureFunction<T>(UserAccount user) {
  return SecureFunction(user) as Expression<Func<T,bool>>; 
 }
 public static Func<ProductDetail,bool> SecureFunction(UserAccount user) {
  return pd => Product.SecureFunction(user).Invoke(pd.ParentProduct);
 }
 public int DetailId { get;set; }
 public string DetailText { get;set; }
 public Product ParentProduct { get;set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public IList<T> GetData<T>() {
 IList<T> data=null;
 Expression<Func<T,bool>> query=GetSecurityQuery<T>();
 using(var context=new Context()) {
  var d=context.GetGenericEntitySet<T>().Where(query);
  data=d.ToList();
 }
 return data;
}
private Expression<Func<T,bool>> GetSecurityQuery<T>() where T : new() {
  var instanceOfT = new T();
        if (typeof(Entities.ISecuredEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
            return ((Entities.ISecuredEntity)instanceOfT).SecurityQuery<T>(GetCurrentUser());
        }
        return a => true; //returning a dummy query
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

First, don't return an `Expression<Func<Parent, bool>>`, that'll require you to compile the expression.  Return simply a `Func<Parent, bool>` instead.

Next, it's all in how you call it:

```
 context.Children.Where(c => c.Name == "bar" && ParentQuery()(c.Dad));

 context.Parents.Where(ParentQuery());
```

Comment: Ah - thats great, and nearly does what I want.
I was using LinqKut to build up the epression within ParentQuery, hence Expression<Func rather than just a plain old Func
Will have a play at changing that and post back how I get on

Glad you pointed my over thinking out - could have ended up with a horribly over complicated solution!

Comment: Ok, nearly there..

In my implementation, ParentQuery is actually declared on an interface as public Func<T, bool> SecurityQuery<T>()

previously I then returned a strongly typed query by building a generic expression via Expression.Lambda().

If I have public Func<AuditGroup, bool> SecurityQuery() how can I convert that to a Func<T, bool> ?
Sure there is an easy way that I am missing??

Comment: Have done some more testing and this is my last hurdle - how can fet Func<Parent,bool> to translate into Func<T,bool> (at runtime, T will be parent)